# python 2.7 to python 3.2 string formatting error

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, python-3.x, string-concatenation

I have this piece of python code:

```
args   =(12, 45, 7854) 
2 result = 123
3 answer = 456
4 print 'Test with data: ', args, ' result: ', result, ' answer: ', answer
```

Now when I run this with python2.7.3 I get this:

```
Test with data:  (12, 45, 7854)  result:  123  answer:  456
```

But when i use python3.2.3 I get this error:

```
print 'Test with data: ', args, ' failed result: ', result, ' answer: ', answer
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I looked for different ways of concatenating or formatting that string but using + or the %s  gives the same error.
Any help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`print` is a function](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function) in py3x:

```
print ('Test with data: ', args, ' failed result: ', result, ' answer: ', answer)
```

Answer (score 1):

In python 3+ you need to put `print( )` because the print `keyword` in 2+ is now a `function` in 3+.

Here are the [Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html) Regarding this.